# Working with zend framework 2.0 with admin and its sub module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want admin module with sub module like below structute,

```
application/
        admin-modules/
                      default/
                              controllers/
                              etc..
                      user/
                           controllers/
                           etc..
```

It was really easy in ZF1 but don't know how to create like this way any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, an Admin Module shouldn't hold business-logic for other modules. Imagine following scenario:

```
/userModule
  - addAction
  - editAction
  - deleteAction
  - viewAction
  - indexAction

/blogModule
  - sameActions
```

Now this makes sense. Every Module can live on its own and there are no hidden dependencies. Now if you want to implement an admin module, it would simply gather information from those modules and provice Access-Control to the actions.

So basically all that your Admin-Module should do is:

- provide a visual representation of routes to the administrative features of your other Modules
- provide [ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#zend-permissions-acl) or [RBAC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#zend-permissions-rbac) functionality

But all logic and even the view-scripts should remain inside each representative Modules

Comment: you mean to say I should put all module folders like for admin and front side in the modules directory and then apply ACL and RBAC functionality on which I have required. Please correct me If I am wrong...

Comment: Yes, a Module should contain all functionality of both public and administrative domains. Later then you can make all administrative functionalities available in any other module (e.g. Admin)